# Alternative of javascript URL supported by IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm trying to create an url object using [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) something like:

```
    var url = new URL($(location).attr('href'));
    url.searchParams.set('myFirstParam', myFirstParam);
    url.searchParams.set('mySecondParam', mySecondParam);
```

Everything working well, but according to [URL Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL#Browser_compatibility) and [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#search=URL) the URL is not compatible with Internet Explorer.
Is there any alternative for URL compatible at least with IE11 ?

Comment: The Resources tab on the caniuse page you linked to has a link to a polyfill, https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#url-and-urlsearchparams - does that not work for you?

Comment: you can just use a polyfill: https://polyfill.io/v3/url-builder/ search for URL, download and include in your project.